# Adding Liquidity Pair in PanCakeSwap V2 Testnet BSC for Burn/Tax Token against tBNB. Not Enabling Right Price Panel

Tags: tokens, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I want to add Liquidity Pair for my Own Token against BNB. but the Price or Right Panel is not Enabling. My Token has Tax and Burn Features. I am using PCS V2 Testnet. I also Tested in V3(it didn't work for the Tax/Burn Token but worked for Very Simple Token).[image: This is PCS V2 BSC Testnet Liquidity Pair Page]

But it is Working for very Simple Token with no Tax/Burn.
If you want more Details, Please ask me